# Ошибки во время билда apk файла в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Пытаюсь сбилдить приложение в Unity, но он выдаёт ошибки. Первое - это предупреждение, что установлен не последний SDK Tools, но когда я нажимал "Обновить", то SDK вообще переставал работать.
Второе - если я нажму на "Использовать текущую версию", то в конце высветится ошибка "Android resource linking failed". Не могу её решить уже долгое время. Началось это после обновления Unity и загрузки библиотек Google для рекламы в проект.

[Информация об ошибках](https://pastebin.com/BvjVZjsf). Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте сначала сбилдить новый пустой проект и посмотрите будут ли ошибки

Comment: Проверил, в новом проекте, после нажатия "Использовать текущую версию", всё нормально билдится. Значит дело в библиотеках Google?

Comment: получается так)

Comment: А какая именно может быть проблема? Неправильно загрузил или ещё что-то?

Comment: бери ошибки и вбей их в гугл, может найдешь чего:)

Comment: Нашёл два решения, но при каждом вылезает ошибка, хотя путь указан верно:

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin

Сейчас буду решать уже эту проблему

Comment: Изменил в переменных сред JAVA_HOME, затем заметил, что ошибка при билде связана с maxAspectRatio. Изменил его на Native и всё заработало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменил Aspect Ratio Mode в настройках для Android на Native и всё заработало. Правда не знаю, почему не работает со своим значением. Также изменил переменную среды JAVA_HOME, что бы она указывала на папку jdk, а не bin.

Comment: `'2,167' несовместимо с атрибутом maxAspectRatio (attr) float`, вам же явно горят, что не соответствует, что тут не понятного? И кстати, [тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.Android-maxAspectRatio.html) все написано, научитесь читать, хотя-бы пользоваться переводчиком. Возможно у вас Культура сбита. а возможно вы просто тулите, не то, что нужно!

Comment: Я уже читал то, что вы скинули, к тому же, если бы вы почитали комментарии, то поняли бы, что я сам увидел эту ошибку. Но проблема в том, что у меня выдавало ошибку даже с начальным значением 2.1.